# get all div element of shadow root containing same class name

Tags: javascript, html, dom, shadow-dom

I have a shadowRoot in my HTML page which I am accessing via  this piece of code

```
var shadow = document.getElementById(
        "3rd-party-div"
      ).shadowRoot;
```

Now I was able to observe that I have two divs with the same class name. I am trying to get both the divs via queryselector but I am able to get only the 1st occurrence of div.

My queryselector code -

```
shadow.querySelector(".potato").addEventListener("click", () => {
            alert("clicked potato");
});
```

Is there a way to get both the divs with same class name?

Comment: Use `.querySelectorAll()`. It returns a `NodeList`, you can call `.forEach()` method on it to iterate over the list and add the event listener on each element in the list.

Comment: `querySelector()` only returns first match found

Comment: ``[ ...shadow.querySelectorAll(".potato") ].forEach(x=>x.addEventListener......``

Comment: This worked perfect! Thank you!

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman there's no need to create an array just to call `.forEach()` method. You can call `.forEach()` on the `NodeList`, returned by `.querySelectorAll`, as well.

Answer (score 0):

As posted by @Yousaf, @charlietfl and @Danny '365CSI' Engelman, querySelectorAll did the trick.

Answer (score -1):

use for loop to loop through the two div elements you want to access.

```
var shadows = document.getElementsByClassName('.3rd-party-div');
for(var i of shadows){
  i.addEventListener('click',()=>{
  alert('clicked ');
 }
}
```

Comment: ``getElementsByClassName`` does not exist on shadowDOM